# Detailed Visual Introduction to Complex Numbers with Problems and Solutions

Tags: soft-question, complex-numbers, online-resources

I'm aware of http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Extras/ComplexPrimer/ComplexNumbers.aspx. It's very detailed and helpful but I'm looking for something with more pictures. It also doesn't have enough problems and solutions.

The Appendix to Calculus by James Stewart has a lot of helpful, revealing pictures. However, it's not advanced enough and there are no solutions to the questions. It should at least cover everything in http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Extras/ComplexPrimer/ComplexNumbers.aspx above. Therefore, it's hard for someone to self-study it to prepare for group theory.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "Visual Complex Analysis" by  Tristan Needham would be a possibility. You might try Google for some web sites. The book has a good deal more than you need.